# How to add an IP to hostname file

Tags: command-line, centos, hostname

I have a Centos 5.8 server. How can I add my server IP address 192.168.20.254 so that it reflects when I run the command `hostname -i`

At the moment the command only shows the loopback IP 127.0.0.1 and the software I am trying to install complains that the server IP is not reflected here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit file `/etc/hosts` and add line:

```
192.168.20.254 this.is.my.host
```

Of course instead of `this.is.my.host` enter proper hostname. You can check it by running `hostname` without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The hostname of the machine can be changed in the following file

```
#/etc/sysconfig/network
```

The

```
#/etc/hosts
```

is for local IP > name resolution (No DNS available)